# Woocommerce PayPal Payment Fee Plugins

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, payment, fee

In my business, I can't cover the payment fee as a seller. I have to let the buyer pay including the payment fee, like 3.99% + 0.3 USD, 4.99% + 0.3 USD, or other currency as another formula. It is based on currencies because I have more than 10 currencies on my sites, not only USD.

I am still looking for the plugs for my WordPress/Woocommerce plugins. I tried to search for it in StackOverflow, but most of them let me update my code, but I don't think that's suitable for me.

I need a WordPress/WooCommerce plugin

Answer (score 0):

Something like [payment method checkout fee](https://wordpress.org/plugins/payment-method-checkout-fee-for-woocommerce/) looks like it might be suitable. Note that the PayPal user agreement specifies "no surcharges", so any processing/handling fees must be the same as other methods (basically you are not permitted to offer buyers a higher total price with PayPal vs. other methods)